# How to plot two linear regressions in a double-log plot (in r)?

Tags: r

I am struggling with how to create a double-log plot in r, and how to plot two linear regressions in this plot. I have succeeded with getting the x-axis transformed to a log-axis, but I can't get the y-axis transformed into a log-axis.

The code I use is this, and it creates the plot in the link below:

```
PR_abs <- lm(PR.Interval..s. ~ log.BM., data = rest)
PR_abs.d <- lm(PR.Interval..s. ~ log.BM., data = dist[4:21,])
   plot(rest$Body.Mass..kg.,rest$PR.Interval..s., xlab = "", type="n", 
    ylab= "PR duration (sec)", pch=20, ylim= c(0,1), log="x", cex=1.4)
points(rest[1:3,]$Body.Mass..kg., rest[1:3,]$PR.Interval..s., cex=1.2,pch=17)
points(rest[4:21,]$Body.Mass..kg., rest[4:21,]$PR.Interval..s., cex=1.2, pch=16)
points(rest[4:21,]$Body.Mass..kg., dist[4:21,]$PR.Interval..s., cex=1.2, pch=1)
lines(rest$Body.Mass..kg.,PR_abs$fitted.values)
lines(rest[4:21,]$Body.Mass..kg.,PR_abs.d$fitted.values,lty=2)
legend("topleft", c("Rest","Exercised","Embryo"), cex=0.8, bty="n", lty=c(1,2,0),
   pch=c(16,1,17))
```

[image]

I have tried using ggplot2 as well, but without success:

```
ggplot(data = rest, aes(x = Body.Mass..kg., y = QT..RR)) +
  geom_point(data = rest, aes(x = Body.Mass..kg., y = QT..RR), shape=1)+
  geom_abline(aes(intercept=coef(QT_rel)[1],slope=coef(QT_rel)[2])) +
  coord_trans(y="log2", x="log2")
```

Any suggestions? :)
Best, Ditte

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e. some of your data, for example using `dput`.

Comment: You have `log="x",`  Have you tried `log="xy",` ?

Comment: _`log`: a character string which contains "x" if the x axis is to be logarithmic, "y" if the y axis is to be logarithmic and "xy" or "yx" if both axes are to be logarithmic._

Comment: Yes, I have tried "xy", and it results in log transformation of the y axis - but then of course my regression lines are not linear anymore. Can I solve that?

Comment: Thank you for your answers!